# Composer require vue ^2.0.1

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I'm using composer and need `vue` in vesion `^2.0.1`. However, I type all this command's and the answer is always:

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

The command's are:

```
composer require vue ^2.0.1
composer require vue "^2.0.1"
composer require vue:^2.0.1
```

What's the correct command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer is used to bring in PHP packages, but Vue is a JavaScript package.

Following the [installation instructions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html), you'll need to install it via npm:

```
$ npm install vue
```

If you don't have npm installed, you can install it from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Comment: Omg...the more I learn, more I realize i'm not that smart. Thanks!